# Eclipse doesn't run embedded Tomcat shutdown sequence when pressing stop button

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, tomcat, shutdown

Usually, when I hit the *stop* button from within Eclipse on the embedded Tomcat instance, the current console is swapped with a new, empty, console window. The former console window is still available though, and if I switch back to it I can see the Tomcat shutdown sequence (with all the messages, warning and such).

But it happens to me, at times, that when I hit the stop button, the server is in fact stopped, but the shutdown process isn't visible — i.e. nothing gets written to the console. The console stays on the last application message.
The Tomcat instance is actually stopped almost instantaneously.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong that can happen in production too, or is this just a quirk in the Eclipse Tomcat plugin?

I never saw such behaviour until a couple of days ago, when I started hunting down never ending threads. I'm putting togheter a simple cleaning strategy — I basically trace the creation of each component that makes use of threads in a singleton, and I call any `interrupt()`, `shutdown()` or `cleanup()` method those components expose in a `ServletContextListener`.

---

I just discovered that when the shutdown process is correctly called, on the debug pane it says:

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>\path\to\java_home\bin\javaw.exe
```

when, instead, the server is suddenly halted, I see:

```
<terminated, exit value: 1>\path\to\java_home\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Is Tomcat getting stopped after this or still keeps running? I was facing similar issue and Tomcat would fail to stop, but I found that when you press stop button in `Console` view (and not the `Servers`), the server stops and stops quickly!

Comment: @Pam Yes, it does, almost instantly as you are experiencing. I've edited.

Comment: missed to mention that I still face this, but gave up since stopping server from console serves the purpose..